# Can't parse links to the different posters from a webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Trying to fetch all the movie posters from left sided area of [this site](https://www.imdb.com/list/ls006385184/) but my script only parses the first one and quits.

How can I get all the movie poster links ending with `.jpg` extension?

```
from selenium import webdriver

def fetch_image_links(driver,link):
    driver.get(link)
    for item in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[href^='/title/'] img.loadlate[src$='.jpg']"):
        print(item.get_attribute("src"))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = "https://www.imdb.com/list/ls006385184/"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    try:
        fetch_image_links(driver,url)
    finally:
        driver.quit()
```

Comment: "[Licensing IMDb Content](https://www.imdb.com/conditions?ref_=ft_cou); Consent to Use Robots and Crawlers: If you are interested in receiving our express written permission to use IMDb content for your non-personal (including commercial) use, please visit our Content Licensing section or contact our Licensing Department. We do allow the limited use of robots and crawlers, such as those from certain search engines, with our express written consent. If you are interested in receiving our express written permission to use robots or crawlers on our site, please contact our Licensing Department."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When page is opened only first couple movies have posters - all other have default image.
You need to scroll down page and wait for the moment when no default images displayed (for all movies posters are loaded)

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 

default_img = "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/G/01/imdb/images/nopicture/large/film-184890147._CB470041630_.png"

def fetch_image_links(driver,link):
    driver.get(link)
    while driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a>img[src='%s']" % default_img):
        driver.find_element_by_tag_name('a').send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
    for item in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[href^='/title/'] img.loadlate[src$='.jpg']"):
        print(item.get_attribute("src"))
```

Comment: One of the best implementation @sir Andersson. Wasn't that a little tricky?

Comment: @robots.txt , Page behavior is complicated, so common approaches are not applicable. This solution is probably not quite obvious... :) Also I don't really like when `while` loop has no *break condition*, but it seem that it should work flawlessly. Let me know if something went wrong or if you want to simply it somehow

Comment: The content of [this link](https://pastebin.com/r88qpGqu) is what I've used finally @sir Andersson.

Comment: @robots.txt , I guess with that code you do more PageDown presses than you need. You can additionally do verification like `if not driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a>img[src$='.png']"): break`

Comment: Would be very happy if you take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54070952/unable-to-fill-in-two-inputboxes-with-dates) @sir Andersson.