# Unable to fill in two inputboxes with dates

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've been trying to fill in two inputboxes with dates (the rest are already filled in) before clicking on the `Search Flights` button to populate the result but can't make it. I've commented out the unsuccessful attempt in my script.

[Website link](https://www.edreams.com/)

I would like the inputboxes to be filled with the following dates `19 Jan, 19` and `7 Feb, 19`.

My attempt so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 

def fill_in_search_boxes(driver,url):
    driver.get(url)
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".airportselector_input[placeholder='From']"))).send_keys("Tatry - Poprad")
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".airportselector_input[placeholder='To']"))).send_keys("London")
    # wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".od-ui-datepicker-display"))).send_keys("Sat. 19 Jan, '19")
    # wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".od-ui-datepicker-display"))).send_keys("Thu. 7 Feb, '19")
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".od-flightsManager-search-flight-button"))).click()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = "https://www.edreams.com/"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
    try:
        fill_in_search_boxes(driver,url)
    finally:
        driver.quit()
```

Comment: what is the error stack trace ? and how did you bypass this "Something about the way you move made us think you were an evil robot." ?

Comment: I made use of proxies to bypass that @cruisepandey.

Comment: If the below answer is not working out for you, you can share the code with proxy and we can have a look again. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to send keys to `div`, not to `input` field. You need to click each `div` and select required date.

Try below to get required output.

```
def fill_in_search_boxes(driver,url):
    driver.get(url)
    #  Select first airport
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".airportselector_input[placeholder='From']"))).send_keys("Tatry - Poprad")
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[.='Tatry - Poprad']"))).click()
    #  Select second airport
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".airportselector_input[placeholder='To']"))).send_keys("London")
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[.='London']"))).click()
    # Select From date
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[.='Departure']"))).click()
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'day_2019-01-19'))).click()
    # Select To date
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[.='Return']"))).click()
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'day_2019-02-07'))).click()
    # Submit form
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".od-flightsManager-search-flight-button"))).click()
```

Note that this allows to handle dates from current/next month. You might need to create function that will handle dates from all months.

P.S. I cannot check this code due to CAPTCHA, so let me know if something wrong with it

Comment: I didn't even notice that you answered @sir Andersson. Your solution hardly fails so I accepted it in advance. I'll let you know if anything goes wrong. Thanks a trillion.

Answer (score 0):

If you check carefully, we cannot write anything in the date fields. they are not the text fields and we have to select input there.
You can try something like:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.className(uiDatepicker)));
        WebElement calendar = driver.findElement(By.className(uiDatepicker));

        //select month
        Select monthSlt = new Select(calendar.findElement(By.className(uiDatepicker + "-month")));
        monthSlt.selectByValue(month);

        //select year
        Select yearSlt = new Select(calendar.findElement(By.className(uiDatepicker + "-year")));
        yearSlt.selectByValue(year);

        //click on the day
        WebElement calTable = driver.findElement(By.className("ui-datepicker-calendar"));
        calTable.findElement(By.linkText(day)).click();
```